# Delete UITableView row from UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm subclassing `UITableViewCell` so I can design my own cells with gestures, etc.

One of the things I'm trying is to delete the cell/row after swiping.

My gesture recognizers are all setup and working nicely, however I'm unsure on how to tell the `UITableView` to delete this object. How can I reference the parent tableView, tell it which row to delete from within the `UITableViewCell` subclass?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a delegate protocol in your `UITableViewCell` subclass, add a method like `cell:didSwipeRightToLeftGesture`, and have your cell call its delegate when that happens. Then when your controller receives that delegate message, delete the row from the data source and update the table view.

You could also use UITableView's built-in swipe-to-delete as well.

Comment: Thanks, any idea on what data to pass back through the delegate to identify which cell to delete?

Comment: @user339946 Just pass the cell through the delegate. The view controller can use the cell to determine whatever it needs (such as the indexPath of the cell).